# Steps Registration Validation For More Conversion Rate

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, forms

My old login form was structured this way:

```
Email
Username
Firstname
Lastname
Password
Repeat Password
Register Button
```

My new structure is:

```
Step 1: 
Email
Proceed Button -> Show the step 2 and hide the step 1
```

Step 2:

```
Username
Firstname
Lastname
Password
Repeat Password
Register Button -> Submit and Register the Form
```

I want to know If there is a way to check the email if its exists, not valid, etc. Now it's store on `$(form).validate({ rules...... });`

So I want to check the email before proceeding to Step 2.

> *Notes:
>   Proceed button is just a plain button I used to translate the divisions for Step 1 and Step 2.*

Comment: call javascript function on pressing proceeding button which verify the email.

Comment: There are a lot of related questions to be answered, e.g. how is your multistep-form set up? Do you also need a solution for the multi-step logic or is it just about the validation? Do you need to validate other fields as well? From the code you are showing it looks like you use jquery. In that case you could make use of existing solutions, e.g. jquery Validation Plugin: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

To validate email already exists with jquery validator plugin, there is one default method called "remote". Here is an rough example of the remote method.

```
<script>
$("#frm-regi").validate({

    rules: {
        email:{required:true,email:true,
            remote:{
                url: "Your ajax file url",
                type: "post",
                data: {email: function() {return $("#email").val();}},
                complete: function(data){
                    return data;
                }
            }
        },  
    },
    messages: {

        email: {required:"Email required",email:"Enter valid email",remote:"Email already exists"},

    },

});
</script>
```

and the ajax file code can be something like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
//echo $_POST['email'];exit;
$email = $_POST['email'];

//execute your mysql query here to get users with specific email id and store into variable $user_count

if(!empty($user_count) > 0) { 
        echo 'false';  
    }
    else {
        echo 'true'; 
    }
}

?>
```

This code is just a example, as you must have to do functional changes as per your coding stuff and all that.